# How to remove custom attribute in product list backend

Tags: product-attribute, custom-options, backend, magento2.2

I added custom tab in product detail page with new attribute. New attribute show in product list backend.

I want to disable new attribute in product list. How can i do?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your Schema code, try to insert this:

```
'used_in_product_listing' => false,
```

like this:

```
$eav->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'vendor_id',
            [
                'group' => 'General',
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Vendor ID',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => NULL,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable'
            ]
        );
```

The attribute will not appear in product grid. Don't forget to delete the old attribute and run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`